# Use Outlook only for sending emails

Tags: mac, osx-lion, microsoft-outlook-2011

I want to add my Gmail account to Outlook, but I only want it to be able to send emails, NOT receive.

The reason for this is I hardly ever use Outlook (I use Gmail's web interface), and I only want my account to be there so I can use things like Word's Mail Merge feature.

Things I've tried: delete the "incoming server" in my account. However, this didn't work as it won't let me remove the server. What I did for the time being is write nonsense in the incoming server, so that Outlook won't be able to connect. However, this causes Outlook to complain with popups that it can't find the server, so I'd still like to know if there's a better solution.

Comment: could you just setup your outlook to use GMAIL via IMAP instead of POP? This would transparently not affect anything on your GMAIL account but do what you're looking for.

Comment: @kobaltz: What do you mean? It's already setup via IMAP. I need neither IMAP nor POP, I just want to use the GMail SMTP server using my Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it, but I found a guide to do what you are looking for here: http://www.codetwo.com/kb/how-to-configure-a-send-only-account-in-outlook/81

1. Setup your gmail account in outlook
2. Choose Tools->Options
3. Click Mail Setup
4. Click Send / Receive
5. Uncheck Receive Mail items on the account
6. Click OK

Can you confirm this works?

Comment: Couldn't get that to work, the option simply isn't there in the Mac version...